# Which sub-topic of Natural Language Processing will help me do this?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

What I am trying to do is identify the context of the query a user might input. So if the user enters "High Proteins", I want to be able to understand that what he means by that is "protein > certain_threshold".

Example 2: User input : "Calories less than 250"
I should be able to understand that what the user means by this is calories < 250

If I am able to do this, I will be able to construct my queries accordingly. Which sub-topic of NLP will help me do this. Any leads woul be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not need NLP if you do not have rich vocabulary. You might just want to use simple dictionaries or regex to specify your queries, just as in a controlled language.

If indeed you need more than this, as you have a very rich vocabulary and complex syntactic relations between your phrases, you should probably start with part-of-speech tagging, chunking, and then maybe parsing. But I wouldn't go that way unless you specifically need to.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this is as a very simple programming language.

You have a set of special key words you want to look for like "Calories" or "Protein" or "LDL" and some operations you want to do like (keyword > 3000) or maybe (%RDA keyword < 2%) that need to be matched. Usually you can do this with a simple expression grammar parser. Depending on what kinds of things you want to connect together (like do you want to say AND or OR or NOT or UNLESS, etc) , and what programming language you want to do this with, it may even be available from a standard library like MARPA (multiple languages) or ANTLR (Java) or Nearly (JavaScript).

Some of the words you might search for include "Earley Parser" or "Context Free Parser" or "Expression Parser". You probably don't need to write your own code, just leverage what already exists.